# ninject setter injection in attribute routing Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, ninject.web.mvc

I am trying ninject.mvc5 to do DI on Web API application.

I added ninject and ninject.mvc5 in my main MVC project. I added one class library for Web API controllers and using attribute routing. I was trying to inject an object using Setter Injection on both MVC project and class library. Object properly injected in MVC project whereas it's null in class library.

Below code block is from MVC application where Stage contains correct object.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Inject]
    public IStage Stage { get; set; }
}
```

Below code is from class library where its failing.

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Inject]
    public IStage Stage { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the bindings:

```
public class WebApiApplication : Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost.NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //RegisterDependencies();
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernal = new StandardKernel();
        kernal.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), 
            Assembly.Load("UserLibrary"), 
            Assembly.Load("StageContracts"), 
            Assembly.Load("StageLibrary"));
        return kernal;
    }
}

public class DependencyMapper : NinjectModule 
{ 
    public override void Load() 
    { 
        this.Bind<IStage>().To<Stage>(); 
    } 
}
```

Not sure what am I missing here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you setup the `DependencyResolver` correctly for Web API?. Also it is advised to do injection via constructor.

Comment: Is it mandatory for ninject.mvc5?

Comment: Where are your bindings?

Comment: My bindings are in MVC Project. Below code I added in Global.asax.cs

    `protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernal = new StandardKernel();
            //Added here required assemblies.
            return kernal;
        }`
Also added DependencyMapper class

Comment: What I mean is, post your bindings so we can see. We need information in order to help you.

Comment: @JuanR `public class DependencyMapper : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            this.Bind<IStage>().To<Stage>();
        }
    }`

Comment: Please post code within the question, not as a comment. I added it for you.

Comment: How are you loading this module into the kernel?

Comment: @JuanR I posted all my code changes. NinjectModule was automatically invoked by kernel.Load() method.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. Have you checked the `DependencyResolver.Current` property? What type of object is it set to?

Comment: The first thing I asked about was  the `DependencyResolver`, which is what the framework uses for injection. If that is not configured correctly then you would experience the issues you are currently getting. Obviously the one for MVC is working. Show the web api config.

Comment: @JuanR Sorry, I dont know whether I interpreted your question correctly. I have not used DependencyResolver in my code. Where can I  check this property?

Comment: It was @Nkosi that first asked about it. You can find it here:  `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current`. It's a static class used by the Mvc infrastructure. Let us know what type of object it is set to.

Comment: Thanks @JuanR and Nkosi. I checked "Current" object's type which is of "Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectDependencyResolver" in both MVC and Class Library.

Comment: That means the resolver is set correctly. It sounds like your module is not being loaded. You can verify this by performing the binding when creating the kernel: `kernel.Bind<IStage>().To<Stage>();`. If this makes the program work, you will know it's the module that is not loaded for some reason. Which library does `DependencyMapper` belong to?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `DependencyMapper`class is not being loaded.

From the documentation concerning the overload you are using to load assemblies:

```
public static Assembly Load(string assemblyString)
```

> assemblyString 
>   Type: System.String 
>   The long form of the assembly name.

For instance:

```
string longName = "system, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
```

Make sure to provide the long names when loading assemblies for the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JuanR and @NKosi.

Finally, I got solution. Since the project solution contains MVC and Web API both, we have to set DependencyResolver of both types - `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver`. Below link is the one helped to solve it.

http://blog.developers.ba/simple-way-share-container-mvc-web-api/